# Following query returning 13 digit timestamp. How to fetch the result in proper format?

Tags: mysql

I would like to get CreatedTime & ResolvedTime in this format Sep 1, 2014 11:49 AM
but currently these two columns are getting 13 digit timestamp values, something like this 1406878545884.

```
SELECT 
 qd.QUEUENAME "Group",
 wo.WORKORDERID "Request ID",
 aau.FIRST_NAME "Requester",
 std.STATUSNAME "Request Status",
 wof.UDF_CHAR16 "Status Reason",
 wo.TITLE "Subject",
 ti.FIRST_NAME "Technician",
 wo.CREATEDTIME "Created Time",
 wo.RESOLVEDTIME "Resolved Time" 
FROM WorkOrder wo 
 LEFT JOIN SDUser sdu ON wo.REQUESTERID=sdu.USERID 
 LEFT JOIN AaaUser aau ON sdu.USERID=aau.USER_ID 
 LEFT JOIN WorkOrderStates wos ON wo.WORKORDERID=wos.WORKORDERID 
 LEFT JOIN CategoryDefinition cd ON wos.CATEGORYID=cd.CATEGORYID 
 LEFT JOIN SDUser td ON wos.OWNERID=td.USERID 
 LEFT JOIN AaaUser ti ON td.USERID=ti.USER_ID 
 LEFT JOIN StatusDefinition std ON wos.STATUSID=std.STATUSID 
 LEFT JOIN WorkOrder_Queue woq ON wo.WORKORDERID=woq.WORKORDERID 
 LEFT JOIN QueueDefinition qd ON woq.QUEUEID=qd.QUEUEID 
 LEFT JOIN WorkOrder_Fields wof ON wo.WORKORDERID=wof.WORKORDERID  
WHERE  
 (((((DATEDIFF(d, DATEADD(s,DATEDIFF(s,GETUTCDATE() ,GETDATE()) + (wo.CREATEDTIME/1000),'1970-01-01 00:00:00'),GETDATE()) <=14) 
AND 
 ((wo.CREATEDTIME != 0) 
AND 
 (wo.CREATEDTIME IS NOT NULL))) 
OR 
 ((DATEDIFF(d, DATEADD(s,DATEDIFF(s,GETUTCDATE() ,GETDATE()) + (wo.RESOLVEDTIME/1000),'1970-01-01 00:00:00'),GETDATE()) <=14) 
AND 
 ((wo.RESOLVEDTIME != 0) 
AND 
 (wo.RESOLVEDTIME IS NOT NULL)))) 
AND 
 (cd.CATEGORYNAME = N'Software Management' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)) 
AND 
 ((woq.QUEUEID IN (1201)) 
OR 
 ((wos.OWNERID = 13501) 
OR 
 (wo.REQUESTERID = 13501))))  
AND 
 wo.ISPARENT=1  
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your SQL, but please consider editing your question to present a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) so that your question is easier to understand.  Particularly for SQL-related questions, knowing the schema (table descriptions including the column names and their declared data types) would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for commenting William. I guess you are right but i just thought of providing the whole query because i havent been able to figure out what and where exactly do i need to make changes to fetch the result in desirable format. I know there is an option of using FROM_UNIXTIME but i am not sure how should i use it in my query.

Comment: i am basically fetching all tickets that were reported in last 14 days or resolved in last 14 days but the value that i get for CREATEDTIME & RESOLVEDTIME Columns is a 13 digit timestamp whereas i would like the report to display a proper time stamp like this Sep 1, 2014 11:49 AM. I would like to schedule this report to run weekly and email the report in .xls format to a distribution list. But i cant schedule it unless i get my query to fetch the result in a desired format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used longtodate instead.

```
SELECT qd.QUEUENAME "Group",
 wo.WORKORDERID "Request ID",
 aau.FIRST_NAME "Requester",
 std.STATUSNAME "Request Status",
 wof.UDF_CHAR16 "Status Reason",
 wo.TITLE "Subject",ti.FIRST_NAME "Technician",
 longtodate(wo.CREATEDTIME) "Created Time",
 longtodate(wo.RESOLVEDTIME) "Resolved Time" 
 FROM WorkOrder wo
```

Comment: LONGTODATE is not a Mysql function this only works from the queryeditor in ServiceDesk Plus, that you should have mentioned in the first place

Comment: That's right, my bad. I am new to SD and have been trying things out. Thanks anyways Mark.

Answer (score 0):

this will format a timestamp to a specific format

```
select date_format(from_unixtime(1264105904),'%b %d, %Y %l:%i %p PDT');
```

the output will look like this

```
Jan 21, 2010 8:31 PM PDT
```

Edit:

your returned timestamp is in milliseconds so to use the above formater devide the result by 1000

```
select date_format(from_unixtime(1406878545884 / 1000),'%b %d, %Y %l:%i %p');
```

Edit 2:

for your query you could use

```
SELECT qd.QUEUENAME "Group",
 wo.WORKORDERID "Request ID",
 aau.FIRST_NAME "Requester",
 std.STATUSNAME "Request Status",
 wof.UDF_CHAR16 "Status Reason",
 wo.TITLE "Subject",ti.FIRST_NAME "Technician",
 date_format(wo.CREATEDTIME,'%b %d, %Y %l:%i %p') "Created Time",
 date_format(wo.RESOLVEDTIME,'%b %d, %Y %l:%i %p') "Resolved Time" 
FROM WorkOrder wo
...
```

Comment: Thanks Markus, as i have mentioned above in my comment to William. I am aware of this "from_unixtime" but i am unsure about implementing it within my query and this is why i have posted whole query here. I am not sure where exactly am i supposed to include this?

Comment: Thanks Markus, i tried this but it threw following exception:java.sql.SQLException: 'date_format' is not a recognized built-in function name.
 at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:365)
 at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2781)
 at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2224)
 at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:628)

Comment: Please note that i am running this query in QueryEditor on ServiceDeskPlus product from ManageEngine. It's a ticketing tool.

Comment: I got it.... instead of date_format i used longtodate and it worked. Thanks for your guidance Markus.